# How do I create a proper Java instance?

Tags: java, class, instantiation

I have created a public class helloworld and I am trying to create an object for class Abc. I have used "new" keyword to create an instance for Abc class.But still I am getting an error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context." in 4th line.
How do I solve this problem?

```
public class helloworld {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Abc obj = new Abc();

    }
    class Abc
    {
        int i;

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `Abc` is an inner class. I would *strongly* advise you to avoid inner/nested classes for the moment if you're new to Java. They can be very confusing.

Comment: you can declare the class Abc as Static as well. IF you want to get past the error.

Comment: Have you trid to add the keyword 'public' at variable i?

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, put class Abc in a different file and make it a public class.

**helloworld.java**

```
public class helloworld {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Abc obj = new Abc();

    }
}
```

**Abc.java**

```
public class Abc
{
    int i;

}
```

Or you can declare your class Abc as `static`:

```
public class helloworld {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Abc obj = new Abc();

    }
    static class Abc
    {
        int i;

    }
}
```

When you create an inner class, it follows the same rule as members of a class: *Static members of a class cannot directly access Instance members*. Thus, you will need to declare Abc as a static class.

PS: please use CamelCasing conventions to name your classes. Ex: Use `HelloWorld` instead of `helloworld`.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: please, for the love of the standard, call it `Helloworld` as of `Classnames` are `CamelCase`.

Comment: I understand, but I did not want to deviate from the the OP already had. That would be for a different time and different question. Anyway, I added a note at the end. ***:)***

Comment: i know :), but that´s something one should start with in my eyes. You get used to the way you write stuff, and if the generall naming standard differs it´s harder to read different code from sources, or get help with your own code when someone is looking over it. It´s just a note for me to OP, reading code and getting help with your own code will be way more easy when following it :)

Comment: You should probably post your comment on the OP's question :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Heed Jon's advise. That said, you can quickly solve this particular problem by changing your inner class into a static class:

```
static class Abc {
    int i;
}
```

I know this might seem a bit weird, but you cannot refer to regular inner classes without first creating an instance of the outer class. Since the main method is static there is no instance of HelloWorld yet. This means it cannot refer to a regular (instance-bound) inner class only to a static inner class.

Arguably a better solution is to create an instance of your class first thing in your main method:

```
// class names should be camel case with an upper case first letter
public class HelloWorld { 

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        HelloWorld app = new HelloWorld();
        app.start();
    }

    // note that this is not a static method
    private void start() {
        Abc obj = new Abc();   
    }

    private class Abc {
        int i;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Abc` is an inner class of `helloworld`. To instantiate it you need an instance of `helloworld`

```
Abc abc = new helloworld().new Abc();
```

or make `Abc` a static inner class.

```
static class Abc {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first awnser is correct but don't be easy. This is the easy way for a eclipse project o similar.

1. Create a ABC class:

   ```
   public class Abc
   {
     int i;

   }
   ```
2. Import in a Hello world class and declare static:

   ```
   import Abc;
   public class HelloWorld{
    private static Abc abc=new Abc();
    public static void main(String[] args){
     //do something 
    }
   }
   ```

All IDE that you use. Help you to import the class : )